# Port Forwarding UDP ports not working

Tags: port-forwarding

For making a Call Of Duty Server using cod-rcon tool, I have port forwarded the following ports: 28960, 28961, 20500 and 20510 (all ports in UDP). If I use [this website](http://portchecker.net/udp.php) to check if the ports are open (in UDP), I find all four are. But if I use [this site](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), it shows all the four ports as closed. I have also disabled my windows firewall (and made exceptions for the program too).

Now, after this setup, when I run the cod-rcon tool, it gives a connection error saying that the port might be down. So, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

UDP scanning is a bit more difficult that TCP scanning as you can not expect to get a response on UDP level (because that depends on the server protocol using the port).

Therefore different UDP scanners using different techniques may come to different results.

If you really want to see if the UDP packets reach your server (for testing port-forwarding) you should use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see if UDP packets for the expected ports are seen.

If you don't see such packets it's a problem of your router or internet connection - otherwise it is a local problem of your PC (e.g. firewall).