# Enabling DMZ for opening ports

Tags: port-forwarding, dmz

I earlier asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/453876/port-forwarding-udp-ports-not-working). There, my problem was that I port forwarded certain ports and turned off Windows Firewall, but still, online port checkers showed that those ports were closed. So, I decided to enable DMZ for my laptop. But even after enabling it, online port checkers still show that the ports are closed (Windows Firewall is still off).

Why are my ports still not open?

PS- I even did the two simultaneously - port forwarding and enabling DMZ - but still, all ports are closed. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a terrible idea to put your computer on the DMZ and disable all firewalls.

Second, may I ask why you're trying to open all unsolicited port requests to your computer?

In your old post, it was suggested that you test with wireshark. Has that been done?